# Use JMeter Siebel CRM Recorder for other applications

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, autocorrelation

The possibility for autocorrelation with the Siebel CRM Recorder is great and I want to use it for non Siebel CRM Applications. I tried something on other applications but nothing happens.

Example Request:

```
<request>
<output local-name="UserID"/>
```

Example Response:

```
<data UserID="123" />
```

Siebel Correlation settings:

```
Reference name: UserID
Request Regex: UserID="(.+?)"
Response Regex: UserID="(.+?)"
Match Number: 1
Match Group: 1
Field To Check: Body
```

When I record the example request, no regex is added... Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the issue is due to this line in the class that creates correlation rules:

- https://github.com/Blazemeter/SiebelPlugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/jmeter/correlation/siebel/SiebelCorrelationEngine.java#L70

If you content type is not HTML then no rule will be created.

You can try removing it and recompile code.

Comment: Indeed that this is the issue.. Thanks for sharing. Lets try to fork this and build is some more generic...

Comment: Happy it helped, feel free to upvote. You should provide a PR so that it's integrated in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use Siebel CRM Recorder for normal [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP)/[HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocols, if you're looking for a recording solution for web applications with automatic correlation you should be using [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder) instead.

Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) for more details.

Comment: Did you have a prove that it doesnt works for http/https? I think a lot of people wants it to save a lot of time... The BlazeMeter Recorder doesn't work for my kind of application, but im aware of it.